# Why need new operator in java but not in c++

Tags: java, new-operator

I been thinking 
Classname ob; 
can create a object in c++
Why need need 
Classname ob=new classname();
In java

Comment: because they are different languages.

Comment: Javascript is not the same as Java! And you are comparing two very different languages, whose only commonality is some syntax.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Java and JavaScript do not share commonality in syntax ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you clearly are not familiar with either, then.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I meant Java and C++. But JavaScript borrows its syntax from the same family and do indeed share a lot of common syntax. Take for example the simple `for` loop which looks just about the same in C, C++, Java, JavaScript and C#.

Comment: @ndugger Java is as similar to JavaScript as C++ or C# is. At that point, you're just saying that programming languages in general are similar to each other, but there is literally no historical connection between JavaScript and Java other than its predecessor LiveScript being made by Oracle.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts familiarize yourself with the ES6+ syntax in javascript and how similar the class syntax is, and then come tell me otherwise. Yes, all of those languages' syntax hail from C, but JavaScript has been heavily based off of Java, and that's simply a fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ and Java have similar syntax but not always means the same.

In Java all objects are references, so when you're doing `Classname obj;` you're creating a empty reference to an object, so you need to assign something to it.

```
Classname obj;
//here obj is pointing to nothing.

obj = new Classname();
//here obj is pointing to a new Classname object
```

The same behavior can be done in C++ with pointers

```
Classname* obj;
//here obj is pointing to nothing.

obj = new Classname();
//here obj is pointing to a new Classname object
```

Now, `Classname obj;` in C++ is very different. It creates the object in the stack, in simple words, the object behaves like fundamentals types (int, bool, float, etc). This behavior isn't supported in Java due it's garbage collected nature.

Comment: obj object is created in heap memory, not stack!